# how to calculate a SNR?

Tags: noise, filters, fourier

i had some question.i have do some some filtering FFT using a matlab program.but,i need to compared the original signal,noise signal,and filtering signal based on SNR.but i dont understand how to calculate the snr ratio.pls help me or give a suggestion method how to compare and analysis the signal.tq

Comment: Another homework question mate? Voting to close. This would be better suited to the DSP stack.

Comment: Hafis - googling using the terms in your question gives me 5 sites that have ways to do this, but I'll migrate to DSP as this is better suited there.